# jQuery Ajax, select и append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Используется jQuery Ajax. Отправляем ajax-запрос:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: {'add_payment': '1', 'get_teams': '1', 'tournament_id': tournament_id},
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#team_select').append(response);
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

Обработчик ajax возвращает текст типа

```
<option value="2">Майами</option>
<option value="3">Техас</option>
```

Опционы не добавляются в `<select id="team_select"></select>`
Почему?

Comment: `console.log("Response:", response);` - ?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю на примере будет понятно!

```js
$('button').on('click', function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  window.location.href, //"ajax.php",
            data: {'add_payment': 1, 'get_teams': 1, 'tournament_id': 1},
            success: function (response) 
            {
                if(response)
                {
                    let data = jQuery.parseJSON(response.trim());

                    data.forEach(function(item, i) 
                    {
                        $("<option/>", {text: item.text, value: item.value, selected : item.selected}).appendTo('#select');
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send AJAX</button>

<select id="select">
    <option value="0">Текст 0</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['add_payment'])){
$_array = 
[
    ["value" => 1, "text" => "Текст 1", "selected" => false],
    ["value" => 2, "text" => "Текст 2", "selected" => false],
    ["value" => 3, "text" => "Текст 3", "selected" => true],
    ["value" => 4, "text" => "Текст 4", "selected" => false]
];

exit(json_encode($_array));}?>
```